# How to disable form dropdown with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, dropdown

I made a dropdown whose contents I retrieve from the database:

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/io2YF.png)

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jP3wT.png)

How can I create conditions when selecting `Received` that the recipient's name field is enabled and besides the recipient's form is disabled ?

```js
var $inputs = $('#kliks');

$('select').change(function() {
  $inputs.prop('disabled', $(this).val() === 'Received');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group col-md-10">
  <label>Ubah status</label>
  <select class="form-control col-lg-10" name="id_status">
    <option value="0">Pilih</option>
    <option value="Foo">Foo</option>
    <option value="Bar">Bar</option>
    <option value="Received">Received</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-10">
  <input type="text" class="form-control kliks" id="kliks" name="" placeholder="nama penerima">
</div>
```

This did not work.

Comment: Your code should be working, *however* the plural on `$inputs` implies you have multiple elements with the same `id` of `kliks` if so, that's the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I edited it

Comment: Thank you. I created a snippet of the code where you can see it works absolutely fine. If it doesn't work for you it means there must be another underlying issue. Check the console for errors. Also, if this HTML is displayed in a modal try using a delegated event handler instead.

Comment: the contents of my dropdown from the database, how to retrieve the word "Received"?

Comment: Your code is already doing that - `$(this).val()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabled dropdown with event

```
jQuery('select').prop('disabled', true);
```

Disabled only dropdown

```
jQuery('select').attr('disabled', true);
```

I have correct the code and dropdown disabled if we selected 'Received' option

try this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){   

    var $inputs = jQuery('#kliks');

    jQuery('select').change(function() {

        var target = jQuery(this);

        var selected_val = target.find(':selected').val(); 

        if (selected_val === 'Received') { alert(selected_val);

            $inputs.prop('disabled', true);

        }

    });

});
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){   

    var $inputs = jQuery('#kliks');

 jQuery('select').change(function() {

  var target = jQuery(this);

  var selected_val = target.find(':selected').val(); 

  if (selected_val === 'Received') { alert(selected_val);

   $inputs.prop('disabled', true);

  }

     

 });



});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control col-lg-10" name="id_status">
    <option value="0">Pilih</option>
    <option value="Foo">Foo</option>
    <option value="Bar">Bar</option>
    <option value="Received">Received</option>
  </select>

<input type="text" name="kliks" id="kliks" value="xyz">
```